# How can I include necessary kernel32.lib, headers - or use the standard dll in a custom application?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I try to build the [Airspy library](https://github.com/airspy/airspyone_host) but I'm having issues, it is not even including Kernel.h headers? I changed Windows SDK in project settings to no effect, and now I am seeing odd errors relating to what seems like perfectly fine syntax:

This is Win8.1 and I tried both in the settings, installing both, but still not compiling. I want to use the library to read audio from radio device but the necessary library isn't compiling (or can I include an Airspy dll and forgo the compile and build step here?)

[image: errors shown]

[image: errors]

[image: all installed sdks]

Answer (score 0):

**>> it is not even including Kernel.h headers?**

This library is not necessarily used in this header file. It may be used in other header files.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib , this is the path of kernel32.lib. 1. Confirm the existence of this file. 2. check your Library Directories of VS and confirm that you fill in the path. This is a common solution to the problem of missing files.